# How to include pydantic excluded fields in dict method

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a class which has an excluded Field (excluded=True). However, for internal code use, I want to use the built-in dict method and include it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would like to add that creating a custom dict method is not an option as i might add more of those fields and i might get a list of those “included excluded fields” to include in a method

Comment: Could you provide an example?